# GAE: Google Apps Provisioning UserEntry getEmail return null

Tags: google-app-engine, google-provisioning-api

I am trying to get user email listing from my domain.

Ok. This is how I do it (code snippet):

```
UserService userService = new UserService("ProvisioningApiClient");
userService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
userService.useSsl();

UserFeed userFeed = userService.getFeed(url, UserFeed.class);

for (UserEntry userEntry : userFeed.getEntries()) {
    logger.warning(userEntry.getEmail().toString());
}
```

The logger will throw NullPointerException error. But when I tried with userEntry.getTitle.getPlainText(), the name is shown.

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: you should answer your own question and accept it, so others see this as an answered question rather then a pending one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

Set a constant

```
private static final string DOMAIN = "mydomain.com";
```

Then get the user name from the userEntry and append string with alias and domain.

```
String userEmail = userEntry.getLogin.getUsername + "@" + DOMAIN;
```